# Angular.js 1.3 One-time binding in ng-bind

Tags: angularjs, ng-bind

In Angular.js 1.3 I can do a one time binding with:

```
{{::name}}
```

But how may I use this in `ng-bind`?

`ng-bind` had some performance improvements in comparison to the `{{` syntax.

Is it supported?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Yes. This works:

```
<span ng-bind="::name"></span>
```