# Can I tell why Angular 1 is calling a rootScope function on every digest

Tags: angularjs

I am having an issue where I have a function like this...

```
$rootScope.canNavigate = function(stateName) {
  return !stateName || Authentication.canNavigate.call(Authentication, $state.get(stateName));
};
```

The problem is this function gets called continuously. The stack trace is different every time but has one thing in common, it is always coming from `$apply`. I have commented out all of the watches that are using this function and it is still happening. Does anyone know why this is happening? I cannot seem to reproduce in a plunker.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a call of this function on any of your html, this function will be called every time angular executes a *digest* cycle in order to do *dirty checking* (See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29474445/why-does-angularjs-execute-function-on-every-digest-loop) on SO in order to get some kind of reference about this)... except you use the *bind once* expression (See [syntax on this article](https://toddmotto.com/angular-one-time-binding-syntax/) and [this on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26735629/angular-js-1-3-one-time-binding-in-ng-bind))

It is called from `$apply` because

> $apply() is used to execute an expression in angular from outside of
>   the angular framework. (For example from browser DOM events,
>   setTimeout, XHR or third party libraries). Because we are calling into
>   the angular framework we need to perform proper scope life cycle of
>   exception handling, executing watches.

but `$apply` is (also) used by the own framework for making a *digest* cycle.

Answer (score 0):

Asiel probably has the right answer depending on your situation, but as to how to prevent it, you can either use the *bind once* expression as Asiel suggests or, if that's not possible for some reason, you could also save the results so you're not calling that service every time.

```
var canNavigateCache = {};

$rootScope.canNavigate = function(stateName) {
  return !stateName
    || canNavigateCache[stateName]
    || canNavigateCache[stateName] = 
         Authentication.canNavigate.call(Authentication, $state.get(stateName));
};
```

This also gives you the ability to clear the cache if you need to by just resetting the cache object (`canNavigateCache = {}`)